# TPKeyboardAvoiding issue

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiscrollview, keyboard, hide

I'm using the TPKeyboardAvoiding project and in doing so have an issue with the size of the scroll view.

The scrolling works great but for some reason it's not using the full screen, despite being set to in the storyboard.

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

WOW that turned out to be a large image! Anyway, it nicely shows the cut off at the top.

**Has any one had a similar issue? How was it resolved?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using autolayouts? I had these problems with autolayouts. Disabling them makes it work.